# Converting Big endian values that i receive on Modbus to float value

Tags: arduino-ide

I am writing some code for Modbus RTU but having a problem converting data received.
below is the code and i am able to communicate with Slave device, however the info i receive back does not make sense at all.
The slave address is 2000 ( hex value) and Datablocks are 2 and Hex response is Float - Big Endian (ABCD) .
However when i view via serial print it makes no sense. Anyone that can help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void loop()
{
  uint8_t j, result;

  uint16_t data[6];


// slave: read (6) 16-bit registers starting at register .. to RX buffer , this address is in Decimal, so convert hex to decimal to use correct address
  result = node.readHoldingRegisters(8192, 2);

  // do something with data if read is successful
  if (result == node.ku8MBSuccess)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
      data[j] = node.getResponseBuffer(j);

Serial.println(data[j]);

    }
  }


  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: What's the baud rate on your serial terminal?

Comment: 9600. it seems i need to convert two datablock arrays to a float value . manual calculations gives me the answer , but not sure how to do it in arduino .

Comment: Ok, and what gets printed?

Comment: two data blocks  [0]  with a value of 17261 and [1] with a value of 6554 what i have figured out is that those two are words which need to be converted from two byte arrays to floating point value . im not sure how to do that ?